# Getting Missing Method error in FSharp.Data

Tags: f#-data

I am trying to use the JsonProvider in FSharp.Data and at run time I get the following:

- $exception  {"Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1 FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntimeWithDesignTimeRules(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)'."}   System.MissingMethodException
      ClassName   null    string
- Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
      HResult -2146233069 int
      HelpLink    null    string
- InnerException  null    System.Exception
      MemberName  null    string
      Message "Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1 FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntimeWithDesignTimeRules(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)'." string
      Signature   null    byte[]
      Source  "OnLineDataAccess"  string
      StackTrace  "   at OnLineDataAccess.TheMovieDatabase.GetSonyPicturesClassics()\r\n   at Film_Data_Exploration.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in E:\Film Data Exploration\Film Data Exploration\Film Data Exploration\Global.asax.cs:line 24"    string
- TargetSite  {FSharp.Data.Runtime.BaseTypes.IJsonDocument GetSonyPicturesClassics()} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
- Static members
- Non-Public members

I can make it go away by switching to an earlier version of FSharp,Data, but then I run into other problems (specifically, that HtmlDocumnent.Elements isn't working properly).  So I thought maybe if I switched from Visual Studio 15 to Visual Studio 17, that might fix the problem, but it didn't.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2023-09-12:**

The guidance on referencing `FSharp.Core` has been updated and [moved here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/docs/fsharp-core-notes.md). In particular, when compiling an *application* (rather than a library), the recommendation is to **not reference** `FSharp.Core` explicitly at all, because the application template you use should already do this in a way that ensures it uses the latest compatible version.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I got the same error, with the same stack trace, trying to use FSharp.Data in LINQPad. I fixed it by installing the NuGet package for `FSharp.Core` version **4.6.0.0**, rather than the LINQPad default of 4.4.0.0. It makes sense that the later version of `FSharp.Data` would have a dependency on something in the newer version of `FSharp.Core`. I'm not sure where my LINQPad installation was getting such an ancient version from.

There's [guidance which recommends always explicitly referencing](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#always-reference-fsharpcore-via-the-nuget-package) the package for the version of `FSharp.Core` you need:

> ### Always reference FSharp.Core via the NuGet package
>
> FSharp.Core is now always referenced via [the NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core).
>
> Some templates for F# libraries use an implicit FSharp.Core package
> reference where the .NET SDK chooses one, e.g. [this kind of thing](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/4327/files#diff-2cc8401da83ac111dbadcb8fb435075eR35). You
> should generally use an explicit reference, especially when creating
> libraries.
>
> If you are using an old-style project file, see the information
> further below.
>
> If using new-style .NET SDK project files, use:
>
> `<PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.5.0" />`

Other headline items from that guidance include:

- Don't bundle FSharp.Core with a library
- Always deploy FSharp.Core as part of a compiled application
- Always reference FSharp.Core via the NuGet package
- Make your FSharp.Core references explicit
- Libraries should target lower versions of FSharp.Core
- Applications should target higher versions of FSharp.Core
- Do not assume FSharp.Core is in the GAC